# Possible to wrap ActionChains move_to_element() in a method?

Tags: python, selenium

Using Python and webdriver-- I'm trying to wrap a selenium call for move_to_element() so I can call it in a page object to be used in a test script.

For example, I have:

```
def find_element(self, locatorMode, Locator):
 element = None
 if locatorMode == LocatorMode.ID:
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(Locator)
 elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.NAME:
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_name(Locator)
 elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.XPATH:
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(Locator)
 elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.CSS_SELECTOR: 
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Locator)
 else:
    raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy.")
 return element

def hover_over(self, locatorMode, Locator):
    self.find_element(locatorMode, Locator).move_to_element()
```

It keeps giving me an attribute error. I've tried to pass a variable into it, with no luck. What am I missing here? Is this possible with this actionchain action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following advice from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576260/5471457

I was able to get this working:

```
 def hover_over(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
    element = self.wait_for_element_visibility(waitTime, locatorMode, Locator)
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element)
    actions.perform()
```