# Calling ActionChains move_to_element() leads to attribute error?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm getting the following error when running my python/selenium script:

**AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'move_to_element'**

What does this particular error message tell? Is it not recognizing move_to_element as a valid action? I am importing the actionchains module as such:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains  import ActionChains
```

I'm able to use the click() and send_keys() actions without issues.

```
def wait_for_element_visibility(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
     element = None
     if   locatorMode == LocatorMode.ID:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.NAME:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.XPATH:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.CSS_SELECTOR:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, Locator)))
     else:
         raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy.")
     return element

 def find_element(self, locatorMode, Locator):
     element = None
     if locatorMode == LocatorMode.ID:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(Locator)
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.NAME:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_name(Locator)
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.XPATH:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(Locator)
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.CSS_SELECTOR: 
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Locator)
     else:
        raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy.")
     return element

 def fill_out_field(self, locatorMode, Locator, text):
     self.find_element(locatorMode, Locator).clear()
     self.find_element(locatorMode, Locator).send_keys(text)

 def click(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
    self.wait_until_element_clickable(waitTime, locatorMode, Locator).click()

 def hover_over(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
     element = Locator
     self.wait_for_element_visibility(waitTime, locatorMode, Locator).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

I'm trying to call it like this:

```
self.hover_over(10,
                        "id",
                        WelcomePageMap['ShareButtonId']
        )
```

Comment: Show the full code. I have no idea why you think an import is the only info we need.

Comment: please share the exact code where you are facing the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem line:

> `self.wait_for_element_visibility(waitTime, locatorMode, Locator).move_to_element(element).perform()`

Here `wait_for_element_visibility()` waits for element's visibility and returns the element itself, then, you are calling `move_to_element()` on a `WebElement` object, but, instead, you need to call it on an [`ActionChains`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) instance passing the previously found element as an argument:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = self.wait_for_element_visibility(waitTime, locatorMode, Locator)

actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(element)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: OK thanks-- I am trying to wrap it in a method so I could call it in another page object for a test script. This wouldn't be possible with move_to_element() then?

Comment: @VinceL sure, updated to reflect the code you've posted. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes sense now. I wasn't aware you couldn't use move_to_element() like that.

Comment: @Vince your missing more things. take a look of the readthedocs page of selenium to be aware of what you can do, and what do you don't need to write yourself. There are methods to wait for elements, called expected_conditions, in conjunction with By(), and will do what you need. Anyway, learning to do yourself will not hurt you... the point is to read what is already done.

Answer (score 0):

This is where your code would fail :

```
 self.wait_for_element_visibility(waitTime, locatorMode, Locator).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

A sample code to use Actions in python goes in here :

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(<id>) //use any of your locator strategy
action = ActionChains(self.driver)
action.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to call 'move_to_element()' as an WebElement object extension, and it is not possible. Even if you import the ActionChain, a WebElement will not have this kind of extension.

You need to do something like it:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

**driver** - Your WebDriver

**element** - The element (WebElement object) that you want to move to.